# Magento: Sort by discount percentage with dropdown menu

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and am facing a problem. In my categories, I need to add a sort by option in the dropdown menu. So far it is easy, except that it is a discount percentage which is not stored in the DB but the calculation of price and discount_price.

I found how to query with the calculation, I just don't know how to set the things together.

How to add a entry in the Dropdown menu?
How to link that entry with a specific module (if needed)?
What to override?

I am a bit confused and would really appreciate your inputs.

**Edit**

I have found a solution.

- Created a module that overrides Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
- Overrided setCollection method
- Added fields to select via Zend ($collection->getSelect()->columns())
- Created a new attribute in the backend whose keyword is the alias of our created field

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Please provide more specific details, may be with some code, on what you have don till now to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

- Created a module that overrides Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
- Overrided setCollection method
- Added fields to select via Zend ($collection->getSelect()->columns())
- Created a new attribute in the backend which keyword is the alias of our created field

That's pretty much it.